# Last modified / recently published

Tags: search-engine-indexing, last-modified

I have a betting tips website so the content relevance period is very short. I and competitors publish content usually within 16-28 hours before the event.

So, my website is usually ranked top 2 for event betting tip requests in the morning and by the evening it could be somewhere in Top 5-6. And I see that the main reason that Google sees my content is not "fresh" compare to other websites in the search results. Below are my competives and I know for sure that they haven't changed their content but Google see it as "very recent" and ranks them higher while I have added few sentences of text as well as users added their comments but google still says it's 1 day+ old. And this things happens every day with all my articles.

Do you have any ideas why Google sees other website as "3 hours ago" or "1 hour ago" (when their content haven't been changed) and mine website not? On screenshots are example for search request "Netherlands croatia prediction" but in russian. The website ranked 1st is a friend of mine and he told me he has no idea why google says that he has very recent content when it was published around 20 hours ago.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7&rlz=1C5CHFA_enRU947RU947&sxsrf=APwXEdeMlDFje9l89mej7NJHM3Q1S_0vZg%3A1686765279545&ei=3_6JZLnuIJyz0PEP0OeK2Ak&ved=0ahUKEwj52bmqqsP_AhWcGTQIHdCzApsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzILCAAQgAQQsAMQywFKBAhBGAFQAFgAYM4DaAFwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAwAEByAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

This is just one example but it happens all the time

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is within sitemap setting. Take a closer look at your competitors sitemaps, also check out this article https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/february-2023/The-Importance-of-Setting-the-lastmod-Tag-in-Your-Sitemap.
I hope that could help.